# Delete connection/ circle in a network diagram using d3.js

Tags: networking, d3.js, geometry, diagram

Please have a look at my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yeQS2/102/) it has the following data associated:

```
rules = [['L5', 'L2'], ['L5', 'L2'], ['L4', 'L2'], ['L2', 'L1'], ['L3', 'L1'], ['L1', 'C1'],  ['C1', 'R2'], ['C1', 'R3'], ['R2', 'R4'], ['R3', 'R6'], ['R3', 'R7']];
```

,my aim here is to have a button that I could use to delete a circle in the diagram. For example when I press e button I delete R3, R2, L5. And when thats done Id need to make a new connection between :
If R3 is deleted then R7 and R6 should point to C1
if R2 is deleted then R5 should connect to C1
If L5 then no new connection should be created.

If You have any advice or suggestions or ideas - would be perfect. of Course I could always iterate through the source and delete unwanted circles and create new connections, but I'm looking for more efficient way than that + Ill also have and undo button which would revert any changes made, but one problem at a time.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

This is known as network projection, and you shouldn't think about it as deleting nodes but rather as transforming nodes into edges. That's not to say that you're wrong about the task from a D3 perspective--you need to delete and create new nodes, but using the proper terminology will lead you to other examples. Multimodal network projection occurs when you take network nodes of one type (say papers) and use them as edges to connect nodes of another type (like people) to transform a network of people and the papers that they wrote into a network of people connected to people they wrote papers with.

To accomplish this with D3, you have to do a few things.

First, you need to have unique ids for your links and edges and use them when you bind the data. This is usually necessary any time that you want to do complex updating and removing of elements with D3:

```
 d3.selectAll(".link")
 .data(links, function (d) {return d.id})

 d3.selectAll(".node")
 .data(nodes, function (d) {return d.id})
```

In your case, these unique ids could be the node names for nodes and the concatenated node names of the connected nodes for links.

With that in place, you can build a simple function like this that fires when you click on a node:

```
 function collapseNode(d,i) {
   force.stop();

   removedLinks = links.filter(function (p) {return p.source == d.id || p.target == d.id});
   filteredLinks = links.filter(function (p) {return p.source != d.id && p.target != d.id});

   filteredNodes = nodes.filter(function (p) {return p.id != d.id});

   //create new links
   //this will have problems with parallel edges
   for (x in removedLinks) {
     for (y in removedLinks) {
       if (removedLinks[x].source != d && removedLinks[y].source != d) {
         filteredLinks.push({source: removedLinks[x].source, target: removedLinks[y].source,
           id: generateAnID})
       }
       else if (removedLinks[x].target != d && removedLinks[y].source != d) {
         filteredLinks.push({source: removedLinks[x].target, target: removedLinks[y].source,
           id: generateAnID})
       }
       else if (removedLinks[x].source != d && removedLinks[y].target != d) {
         filteredLinks.push({source: removedLinks[x].source, target: removedLinks[y].target,
           id: generateAnID})
       }
       else if (removedLinks[x].target != d && removedLinks[y].target != d) {
         filteredLinks.push({source: removedLinks[x].target, target: removedLinks[y].target,
           id: generateAnID})
       }
     }
   }
   d3.selectAll(".node").data(filteredNodes, function(d) {return d.id})
   .exit()
   .remove();

   d3.selectAll(".link").data(filteredLinks, function(d) {return d.id})
   .exit()
   .remove();

   d3.selectAll(".link").data(filteredLinks, function(d) {return d.id})
   .enter()
   .append("line)
   .attr("class", "line")

   force.start();

 }
```

Comment: Its a really good read. I was more interested in the first part of the answer than the code part :) thanks a lot, I will defilement give this a go and come back to You how it went

Comment: First of all thanks for Your answer, I had a go. I made sure that all my circles and connecting liens have ids now. Then I went onto the function. Could You please elaborate a bit more how it works ?  For example, what are You passing in as arguments for this functions ? If its not a huge problem maybe You could edit an existing http://jsfiddle.net/yeQS2/103/ , Ive updated it so all elements have an Id now. Thanks for Your help

Comment: could You please comment a bit more on Your answer when You have a minute